# How to make datatable fixed height and fixed pagination

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am using DataTables for jQuery plugin for my table. I want my table height always end at the fixed pagination.

I want to achieve this for the user so that they don't need to scroll in webpage, only in datatable..

This is what exactly want I to achieve.. I have no idea how to get this:

[image: Layout]

Comment: this this,please. in your css .DataTables{ width: 1fr } and add the class="DataTables" in your html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to set in your `footer{position:fixed; bottom:0; width:100%;}` that would help to make footer always stays at the bottom of the viewport. (I'm assuming that you want to achieve that).

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS I found that will force a DataTable.Net to a fixed height (change min-height to your desired size). Info on left, pager control on right.

```
div.dataTables_wrapper { min-height: 530px; }
div.fg-toolbar.ui-toolbar.ui-corner-tl { position: inherit; }
div.fg-toolbar.ui-toolbar.ui-corner-bl { position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100% }
div.dataTables_paginate { position: relative; float: right;}
```